# Bootstrap ekkolightbox not support tif/tiff images?

Tags: lightbox

I have used the tiff image and on click the image should open in the lightbox. But ekko-lightbox does not seems to work with tif/tiff images.

Comment: provide some code, what is your approach?

Comment: it was a normal approach with the tiff images